# wpf select listbox datatemplate manually when adding item to list

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox, datatemplate

maybe a noob question... Can I select the Datatemplate of an item manually on adding to the Listbox?
Say:

```
    Item1 -> template1
    Item2 -> template2
    Item3 -> template2
    Item4 -> template1
```

All items are strings, and the Listbox will be filled (via Viewmodel Property) on runtime

I just need some manual designing...

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: I think you're looking for [`ItemTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @dkozl: thanks for the reply. So I have to create a Class for the Items with a Property to choose template....?

Comment: You need to create custom class that inherits from `DataTemplateSelector` and override `SelectTemplate` method which gives you item and based on that item return `DataTemplate` you want. You then set your custom `DataTemplateSelector` as `ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector`. Check the example on MSDN

Comment: I already have this class :) My "problem" is, that the items I pass there are always strings, so  I don't see how to decide the right datatemplate to return. Therefore I will need a custom item class with a property too, so I can parse in a select case. Right?